# Blender gltf exports unrelated textures/materials

Tags: export, gltf

When I export gltfs the resulting files are getting quite big. I uploaded the files to https://gltf.report/ to see whats going on. There i saw, that a bunch of unrelated files got exported as well. a couple textures, materials and all my scenes as well. Not the scenes objects but i think it exports some scene settings wich makes no sense.
After i saw this I added the default cube and exported that with all default settings. Still the same (Its always the same textures and materials).
The default cubes gltf file size is 4mb. With a fresh instance of blender it exports the cube with only 2kb.
I think when copying everything to a fresh blender instance it might work but i have lots of scripts and different scenes so that would involve a lot of work.
Does anybody know if there is a simpler way to fix this?

heres the default cubes export: https://drive.google.com/file/d/1STobQML3yTnaAK2IEHU27No9Fr0oD1Tg/view?usp=drive_link
you can upload it to https://gltf.report/ to see whats inside

Comment: Hello and welcome. While files, images, and external videos or links may be helpful additions they should not be the only way to obtain information about your issue. Don't make understanding your question rely on downloading a file, watching a video or visiting an external site. Use the builtin tools to upload [images](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491) or [gifs](https://blender.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/963), along with thoroughly explaining the problem in written form so it can be indexed and searched for thus helping future visitors with similar issues.

Comment: Hello. Somebody correct me if im wrong but i think my problem and question is very clear just by reading it. No need to download the file. It only might be helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple scenes in your Blender file, the exporter may try to include all of them by default.  You can change this behavior on the export settings panel, on the right side of the file dialog.  Turn on the "Active Scene" checkbox to limit the export to only the currently active scene.

In the same area of the UI, additional controls are available to limit the export in a variety of other ways, such as current selection, currently visible, etc.

[image: screenshot of active scene checkbox]